I'm trying to edit a board in Trello using Postman and I don't know how to change some variables in the JSON file
So this is what my JSON file body contains when I make a request.
{
    "id": "fffr3g4h234h2j34g23hj4g324hg32",
    "name": "testBoard",
    "desc": "This is the new boards description.",
    "descData": {
        "emoji": {}
    },
    "closed": false,
    "idOrganization": "n4b23h432b4hj23g432h4j32b423",
    "idEnterprise": null,
    "pinned": false,
    "url": "https://trello.com/b/3e23/testboard",
    "shortUrl": "https://trello.com/b/3e23",
    "prefs": {
        "permissionLevel": "private",
        "hideVotes": false,
        "voting": "disabled",
        "comments": "members",
        "invitations": "members",
        "selfJoin": true,
        "cardCovers": true,
        "cardCounts": false,
        "isTemplate": false,
        "cardAging": "regular",
        "calendarFeedEnabled": false,
        "hiddenPluginBoardButtons": [],
        "switcherViews": [
            {
                "viewType": "Board",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "viewType": "Table",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "viewType": "Calendar",
                "enabled": false
            },
            {
                "viewType": "Dashboard",
                "enabled": false
            },
            {
                "viewType": "Timeline",
                "enabled": false
            },
            {
                "viewType": "Map",
                "enabled": false
            }
        ],
        "background": "blue",
        "backgroundColor": "#0079BF",
        "backgroundImage": null,
        "backgroundTile": false,
        "backgroundBrightness": "dark",
        "sharedSourceUrl": null,
        "backgroundImageScaled": null,
        "backgroundBottomColor": "#0079BF",
        "backgroundTopColor": "#0079BF",
        "canBePublic": true,
        "canBeEnterprise": true,
        "canBeOrg": true,
        "canBePrivate": true,
        "canInvite": true
    },
    "labelNames": {
        "green": "",
        "yellow": "",
        "orange": "",
        "red": "",
        "purple": "",
        "blue": "",
        "sky": "",
        "lime": "",
        "pink": "",
        "black": "",
        "green_dark": "",
        "yellow_dark": "",
        "orange_dark": "",
        "red_dark": "",
        "purple_dark": "",
        "blue_dark": "",
        "sky_dark": "",
        "lime_dark": "",
        "pink_dark": "",
        "black_dark": "",
        "green_light": "",
        "yellow_light": "",
        "orange_light": "",
        "red_light": "",
        "purple_light": "",
        "blue_light": "",
        "sky_light": "",
        "lime_light": "",
        "pink_light": "",
        "black_light": ""
    }
}

and this is what I put in the PUT request in the body:
{
    "desc" : "This is the new boards description.",
    "prefs" : {
        "background" : "orange",
        "backgroundColor" : "#FFA500"
    }
}

The description changes but the background and background color data doesn't change.
Any ideas how can I change the background to let's say orange?

This way can change background and background color in input body of JSON.
In Pre-request Script tab
let BackgroundName = pm.environment.get("BackgroundName");
let BackgroundColor = pm.environment.get("BackgroundColor");

let body = {
    "prefs": {
        "background": "blue",
        "backgroundColor": "#0079BF"
    }
}
body.prefs.background=BackgroundName;
body.prefs.backgroundColor=BackgroundColor;

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("body", JSON.stringify(body));

In Body tab
{{body}}

Demo
I will demo by local mock trello server.
It provides one API
PUT http://localhost:3000/v1/data

Will receive full JSON body.
And return response only this data.
background and backgroundColor copy from input body.
{
    "desc": "This is the new boards description.",
    "prefs": {
        "background": "green",
        "backgroundColor": "#008000"
    }
}

1 Server code
Save as server.js
// Importing express module
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Creating an instance of express
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

// Using bodyParser to parse JSON bodies into JS objects
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Defining the PUT endpoint
app.put('/v1/data', (req, res) => {
    const { desc, prefs } = req.body;

    // Creating the response object based on the specific keys from the input JSON
    const response = {
        desc: desc,
        prefs: {
            background: prefs.background,
            backgroundColor: prefs.backgroundColor
        }
    };

    // Sending the response object as JSON
    res.json(response);
});

// Starting the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

2 Install dependency
npm install express body-parser

3 Run it
node server.js

4 Set Environment Variable in demo by Postman
BackgroundNames : ["green","yellow","orange","red","purple","blue"]

BackgroundColors: ["#008000", "#FFFF00", "#FFA500", "#FF0000", "#800080", "#0000FF"]


5 Create PUT request
Name as "Dynamic Color"
URL
PUT http://localhost:3000/v1/data


6 Set Pre-request script tab
let BackgroundNames = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("BackgroundNames"));
let BackgroundColors = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("BackgroundColors"));

pm.environment.set("BackgroundName", BackgroundNames.shift())
pm.environment.set("BackgroundColor", BackgroundColors.shift())

pm.environment.set("BackgroundNames", JSON.stringify(BackgroundNames));
pm.environment.set("BackgroundColors", JSON.stringify(BackgroundColors));

let BackgroundName = pm.environment.get("BackgroundName");
let BackgroundColor = pm.environment.get("BackgroundColor");

let body = {
   "id": "fffr3g4h234h2j34g23hj4g324hg32",
    "name": "testBoard",
    "desc": "This is the new boards description.",
    "descData": {
        "emoji": {}
    },
    "closed": false,
    "idOrganization": "n4b23h432b4hj23g432h4j32b423",
    "idEnterprise": null,
    "pinned": false,
    "url": "https://trello.com/b/3e23/testboard",
    "shortUrl": "https://trello.com/b/3e23",
    "prefs": {
        "permissionLevel": "private",
        "hideVotes": false,
        "voting": "disabled",
        "comments": "members",
        "invitations": "members",
        "selfJoin": true,
        "cardCovers": true,
        "cardCounts": false,
        "isTemplate": false,
        "cardAging": "regular",
        "calendarFeedEnabled": false,
        "hiddenPluginBoardButtons": [],
        "switcherViews": [
            {
                "viewType": "Board",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "viewType": "Table",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "viewType": "Calendar",
                "enabled": false
            },
            {
                "viewType": "Dashboard",
                "enabled": false
            },
            {
                "viewType": "Timeline",
                "enabled": false
            },
            {
                "viewType": "Map",
                "enabled": false
            }
        ],
        "background": "blue",
        "backgroundColor": "#0079BF",
        "backgroundImage": null,
        "backgroundTile": false,
        "backgroundBrightness": "dark",
        "sharedSourceUrl": null,
        "backgroundImageScaled": null,
        "backgroundBottomColor": "#0079BF",
        "backgroundTopColor": "#0079BF",
        "canBePublic": true,
        "canBeEnterprise": true,
        "canBeOrg": true,
        "canBePrivate": true,
        "canInvite": true
    },
    "labelNames": {
        "green": "",
        "yellow": "",
        "orange": "",
        "red": "",
        "purple": "",
        "blue": "",
        "sky": "",
        "lime": "",
        "pink": "",
        "black": "",
        "green_dark": "",
        "yellow_dark": "",
        "orange_dark": "",
        "red_dark": "",
        "purple_dark": "",
        "blue_dark": "",
        "sky_dark": "",
        "lime_dark": "",
        "pink_dark": "",
        "black_dark": "",
        "green_light": "",
        "yellow_light": "",
        "orange_light": "",
        "red_light": "",
        "purple_light": "",
        "blue_light": "",
        "sky_light": "",
        "lime_light": "",
        "pink_light": "",
        "black_light": ""
    }
}
body.prefs.background=BackgroundName;
body.prefs.backgroundColor=BackgroundColor;

console.log("body.prefs.background: " + body.prefs.background);
console.log("body.prefs.backgroundColor: " + body.prefs.backgroundColor);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("body", JSON.stringify(body));


7 Set Body tab
{{body}}


8 Set Tests tab
console.log("BackgroundName: " + pm.environment.get("BackgroundName"));

let BackgroundNames = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("BackgroundNames"));
if (BackgroundNames.length > 0){
    postman.setNextRequest("Dynamic Color");
}


9 Run API
Press Send Button
The response of body will be changed the background and backgroundColor
First Run
Result
{
    "desc": "This is the new boards description.",
    "prefs": {
        "background": "yellow",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFF00"
    }
}


Result
{
    "desc": "This is the new boards description.",
    "prefs": {
        "background": "orange",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFA500"
    }
}


Third run
{
    "desc": "This is the new boards description.",
    "prefs": {
        "background": "red",
        "backgroundColor": "#FF0000"
    }
}

And so one.
10 Auto Run
After reset varaibles
BackgroundNames : ["green","yellow","orange","red","purple","blue"]

BackgroundColors: ["#008000", "#FFFF00", "#FFA500", "#FF0000", "#800080", "#0000FF"]


Result
6 times POUT call by changing background color


